# gulp - The following tasks did not complete

Tags: javascript, gulp

Только начал изучать gulp и при первом же вызове функции у меня вылезла странная ошибка. в консоли конечно вывелось то, что я хотел, но дальше непонятная ошибка. Подскажите пожалуйста. В гугле нормального объяснения не нашел. Код весь на скрине

[image: gulp]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
gulp.task('test', done => {
  // code...
  done();
});
```

В твоем случае код должен так выглядеть.Так можно делать только в твоем случае. Обычно в проектах таск выглядит так, как делал ты

```
gulp.task('cleanimg', function() { //из моего проекта
    return del(['app/img/@*'], { force:true })
});
```

Comment: спасибо большое)

Comment: если помогло отметь ответ как правильный